# how can I duplicate SwiftUI object

Tags: button, swiftui, group

in SwiftUI can I see the tree structure of the ui?  in the sense, view, button ... if I want to duplicate a button or something else what can I do?  thank you .

Comment: What do you mean by duplicate ? When you declare a view strut you declare a type that you can use in multiple places  by initialising a new structure element : eg : MyStruct()

Comment: i saw a video in swiftui 2.0 could create a duplicate of a hstack.  but it seems that with the new version of swiftui nom it can be done.  practically the part of the live view was editable.